# Encrypt using RSA Certificate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, rsa, x509certificate

I used the following code in a playground to Encrypt a string using RSA. I need the encryption to happen using certificate itself, by extracting the key on the go, rather than the key getting extracted separately and then encrypting.

```
import Foundation
import Security


struct RSA {

    static func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: String?) -> String? {
        guard let publicKey = publicKey else { return nil }

        let keyString = publicKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\t", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        print(keyString)
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: keyString) else { return nil }
        print(data)
        var attributes: CFDictionary {
            return [kSecAttrKeyType : kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                    kSecAttrKeyClass : kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits : 2048,
                    kSecReturnPersistentRef : kCFBooleanTrue as Any] as CFDictionary
        }

        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
        guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, attributes, &error) else {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return nil
        }
        return encrypt(string: string, publicKey: secKey)
    }

    static func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: SecKey) -> String? {
        let buffer = [UInt8](string.utf8)

        var keySize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey)
        var keyBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keySize)

        // Encrypto should less than key length
        guard SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, buffer, buffer.count, &keyBuffer, &keySize) == errSecSuccess else { return nil }
        return Data(bytes: keyBuffer, count: keySize).base64EncodedString()
    }
}


var pemString = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----##Base 64 encoded certificate string##-----END CERTIFICATE-----"


let password = "abcde"
let encryptedPassword = RSA.encrypt(string: password, publicKey: pemString)
print(encryptedPassword as Any)
```

However it is throwing the following exception:

> Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<__C.CFErrorRef>(_value: Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "RSA public key creation from
>   data failed" UserInfo={NSDescription=RSA public key creation from data
>   failed}))

How to do the same properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in question doesn't extract the Key from certificate. Rather, it tries to create the `SecKey` using the certificate string itself. The correct way to do the same is to create a `SecCertificate` object from the certificate data, then create a `SecTrust` using the certificate data. Then using the trust, copy the public key to make `SecKey` object.

The final code will look something like this:

```
import Foundation
import Security


struct RSA {

    static func encrypt(string: String, certificate: String?) -> String? {
        guard let certificate = certificate else { return nil }

        let certificateString = certificate.replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\t", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        print(certificateString)

        // Convert the certificate string to Data
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: certificateString) else { return nil }
        print(data)

        // Create SecCertificate object using certificate data
        guard let cer = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data as NSData) else { return nil }

        var trust: SecTrust?

        // Retrieve a SecTrust using the SecCertificate object. Provide X509 as policy
        let status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(cer, SecPolicyCreateBasicX509(), &trust)

        // Check if the trust generation is success
        guard status == errSecSuccess else { return nil }

        // Retrieve the SecKey using the trust hence generated
        guard let secKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust!) else { return nil }

        return encrypt(string: string, publicKey: secKey)
    }

    static func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: SecKey) -> String? {
        let buffer = [UInt8](string.utf8)

        var keySize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey)
        var keyBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keySize)

        // Encrypto should less than key length
        guard SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, buffer, buffer.count, &keyBuffer, &keySize) == errSecSuccess else { return nil }
        return Data(bytes: keyBuffer, count: keySize).base64EncodedString()
    }
}


var pemString = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----##Base 64 encoded certificate string##-----END CERTIFICATE-----"


let password = "abcde"
let encryptedPassword = RSA.encrypt(string: password, certificate: pemString)
print(encryptedPassword as Any)
```

The only change is in the `static func encrypt(string: String, certificate: String?) -> String?` function.

Comment: How would this change if we were using a private key that was encrypted with a passcode?

Comment: Will have to browse through the documentations I guess to figure out a proper solution. If you are not able to figure out a solution, please put up a seperate question for the same.

Comment: Thanks, I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428695/retrieve-seckey-from-rsa-private-key-string-encoded-with-passphrase-in-swift-or